# php sleep() function not work properly inside a function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a share host and I run following script on **public_html/testsleep.php** file:

```
$i = 0;
while(true) {
    sleep(15);
    echo '1';
    if ($i++ > 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

it work properly,
but when i move this script inside a **laravel** class, for example in **AdminController** it does not work more that 10 second and it exit without any error message

Any Idea?

### EDIT

My code in **AdminController**:

```
$i = 0;
while(true) {
    Log::info('work');
    sleep(15);
    Log::info('nottttttttttttttt work');
    if ($i++ > 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, Laravel is probably calling [set_time_limit()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) somewhere.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I dont think so, i echo ini_get('max_execution_time') and it's properly 300

Comment: @AlexHowansky Time spent `sleep`ing isn't counted towards that limit - it's strictly for PHP execution time (i.e. not sleep, DB queries, etc)

Comment: Please provide code where you are using is inside of Admin controller and how you are calling that code.

Comment: @Aknosis I edit the question

Comment: I tried your code in my controller and it worked. The page loaded in `1.3` min.

Comment: @ChinLeung that right, this code works for myself in another host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem caused by LiteSpeed,

My service provider add some code to .htaccess file and it's fixed

I search and find this link useful:
https://kb.netvirtue.com.au/knowledgebase/litespeed-increase-execution-time/